# cast a pointer to int in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, reference, casting

I have this array "r->phy_addr" defined as follows:

```
int array [r->numpgs];
r->phy_addr= &array[0];
```

now I want to pass element zero of the array to a function that takes "int" as an arugument:

```
add(int x){};
```

if I do like this

```
add(r->phy_addr[0]);
```

then an error of "can't pass a pointer as an int"

How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly casting the argument: add((int)r->phy_addr[0]);

Comment: @Fred yes it doesn't work :(

Comment: What's the type of `phy_addr` ?

Comment: what is phy_addr declared as?

Comment: In case it wasn't obvious. when it comes to questions of pointers and their assignments and dereferencing, if you get errors like this, you probably have a pointer-type wrong. But we can't tell for sure without you showing us the type declarations of the aforementioned variables.

Comment: @shaklasah: "I have this array `r->phy_addr` defined as follows...". The code you posted does not show how `r->phy_addr` is declared or defined. Post the declaration of `r->phy_addr`.

Answer (score 3):

If the compiler complains about `r->phy_addr[0]` beng a pointer, then `r->phy_addr` must have pointer-to-pointer type (`int **` most likely). In that case your problems begin even earlier. This

```
r->phy_addr = &array[0];
```

is already invalid, since you are assigning `int *` value to a `int **` object. The compiler should have told you about it.

In other words, your call to `add` is not a problem. Forget about the call to `add`. It is too early to even look at that call. You have other problems that have to be solved well before that one.

What is `r->phy_addr`? Is it supposed to have `int **` type? If so, why are you assigning it as shown above? Why are you ignoring compiler diagnostic messages triggered by that invalid assignment?

Answer (score 2):

try  `add(*(r->phy_addr[0]));`
it should work

Comment: "it should work" No it shouldn't. In order for this to work, `phy_addr` needs to be an `int **`, i.e. it must point to an `int *`. There is no `int *` anywhere in the program it could possibly point to. Moreover, in the code shown, `phy_addr` is assigned to `&array[0];`, i.e. it points to the first element of `array`, which is an int. `*(r->phy_addr[0])` as you suggest would dereference `phy_addr` twice, which would try to dereference the first element of `array` (an int) as if it were a pointer. This cannot possibly be good.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that r->phy_addr has `int **` type.
So `r->phy_addr[0]` gets `int *` type, and then
compiler warns you that the argument should be `int` type,
rather than `int *` type.

Change the type of `r->phy_addr` to `int *`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
add(*(r->phy_addr[0]));
```

? Since, **apparently**, `r->phy_addr[0]` is a pointer.

Comment: The extra parens are not needed.

Comment: @ouah I follow a simple rule - if I'm not sure, I add parens. :)

Comment: There is a simple rule: postfix operators always have higher precedence than unary operators.

Comment: I like the parens here, I would keep it for the benefit of devs like me who don't memorize precedence rules